# Google Places Autocomplete - how to access raw user input

Tags: android, google-places-api, google-places-autocomplete

I have an activity which gives the user the option to enter their address details (address text, building/floor/apartment number).

I want to access/save what the user writes in the AutocompleteSupportFragment, especially in cases when the Places Autocomplete API doesn't find any results so I could use what the user inputted directly.

What I tried so far:
1- The AutocompleteSupportFragment.setOnPlaceSelectedListener's onError method is not called.
2- Adding a TextWatcher to the AutocompleteSupportFragment.a (where a is a reference to the EditText) to get the data in afterTextChanged, no data is captured.

XML code:

```
 <fragment
            android:id="@+id/address_autocomplete_fragment"
            android:name="com.google.android.libraries.places.widget.AutocompleteSupportFragment"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

Java code:

```
Places.initialize(getApplicationContext(), Constants.PLACES_API_KEY);


// Initialize the AutocompleteSupportFragment.
autocompleteFragment = (AutocompleteSupportFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.address_autocomplete_fragment);

// Specify the types of place data to return.
autocompleteFragment.setPlaceFields(Arrays.asList(Place.Field.ID, Place.Field.NAME, Place.Field.LAT_LNG, Place.Field.ADDRESS));

autocompleteFragment.setCountry("EG");
autocompleteFragment.a.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

    }

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
        Log.d(TAG, "User text: " + s);
    }
});

// Set up a PlaceSelectionListener to handle the response.
autocompleteFragment.setOnPlaceSelectedListener(new PlaceSelectionListener() {
    @Override
    public void onPlaceSelected(Place place) {
        //Get info about the selected place.
        Log.d(TAG, "Place: " + place.getName() + ", " + place.getId());
    }

    @Override
    public void onError(Status status) {
        //Handle the error.
        Log.d(TAG, "An error occurred: " + status);
    }
});
```

[image]

Comment: Did you find your answer?  If so, can you tell me what you did?

Comment: @LizG Unfortunately not, it's still the same as it is.